# How to specify figure sizes with rmarkdown html notebooks

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I have not been able to get an rmarkdown html notebook to pay attention to figure sizes that I specify.  I've tried using `knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width=7)` and I've tried including the following:

```
output:
  html_notebook:
    fig_height: 5
    fig_width: 7
    toc: yes
    toc_float:
      collapsed: yes
```

What is the proper way to specify sizes and how does one vary the image size for different code chunks?

I'm confused about html notebook workflow in general, e.g., to run all the code then render it I've been using Run ... Run All then clicking on Preview.  Is that the preferred method?

I'm using the latest version of the `rmarkdown` and `knitr` packages, R, and RStudio preview.

Comment: Specifying `knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.height=5, fig.width=7)` works for me (R 3.3.1, rmarkdown 1.0, knitr 1.13.1, OSX Yosemite). Specifying them in the individual chunk options also works for me (e.g., `\`\`\`{r fig.height=2, fig.width=7}\`\`\``

Comment: To compile the notebook, you would typically either click the "knit" button in RStudio for interactive compilation or, in a separate R script, you could do `rmarkdown::render("my_html_notebook.Rmd", "my_output_file.html")`. I haven't created an html_notebook before, so it's possible the workflow is slightly different, but both of those approaches worked on a sample html_notebook I just created.

Comment: I have a setup function that defines aliases for figure height and width (h and w).  When I knit to html those aliases are respected in the resulting html file.  When I Run All then Preview the aliases are not respected.  Thanks for the render command.  When an html notebook is in effect, RStudio does not have a "Knit" button, only a pull down where it says Preview that gives you the option to "knit to html" (which does not create an html notebook but creates a regular html report).

Comment: I actually have a "Knit" button with the sample html_notebook I created. I'm using RStudio 0.99.903 (latest non-preview version). Based on the [`R Notebook` documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html) it looks like Notebook functionality is only available in the preview release, which probably explains the interface differences.

Comment: Note that the `rmarkdown::render()` call above does not render `plotly` graphics.

Comment: I was struggling with this challenge myself and discovered that the figure dimensions specified in the YAML metadata (fig_height and fig_width) appear to control the container size for image (up to the page container, or something like), but the knitr chunk options (fig.height and fig.width) control the original image size. The original image is then resized to fit within the container.

Further I believe that the html_notebook output format (*.nb.html) has a different stylesheet from the html output format, and that figure sizes may behave differently for the two different output formats.

Comment: This is very helpful.  I guess that what we really need is a variable container size, which I don't see how to do with YAML.